# cbgv UpdateView and modelform, html form doesn't submit data

Tags: django, forms, django-class-based-views

In django 1.6, the template/form below doesn't submit a post request after i hit the "Submit" button, but this all worked when i'm running django 1.5.3 !
What I am missing ?

Here's my simplified snippets:

## models.py

```
class Codici(models.Model):
    PIECES = 'pcs'
    GRAM = 'g'
    METRE = 'm'
    SI_UNITS_CHOICES = (
        (PIECES, 'pezzi'),
        (GRAM, 'grammi'),
        (METRE, 'metri'),
    )
    codice = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    descrizione = models.TextField(blank=True)
    stock = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    fornitori = models.ManyToManyField(Fornitori)
    si_unit = models.CharField(max_length=3,
                                       choices=SI_UNITS_CHOICES,
                                       default=PIECES)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^codici/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
    CodiceUpdateView.as_view(),
    name='update'),
```

## forms.py

```
class CodiceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Codici
        fields = ('codice', 'descrizione', 'stock', 'si_unit',
                  'fornitori')
```

## views.py

```
class CodiceUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Codici
    form_class = CodiceForm
```

## app/codice_form.html (template)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form|crispy }}
      <button type="submit" value="Update">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'it doesn't submit a post request'? Do your browser's developer tools show any requests being made? Could there be a javascript error? What is the difference in the rendered html between Django 1.5 and 1.6?

Comment: I mean that when I press the submit button nothing happen and i don't see a request on the console (tried with firebug and chrome).

Comment: And i don't see differences between the rendered html of django 1.5.3 and django 1.6

Comment: i also checked the csrf token and there is, rendered as normal

Comment: That's strange. I don't understand how upgrading Django on the server side can prevent the browser from submitting a form if there's no change in the rendered html. Are there any error messages on the console in the developer tools? I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: I don't have any error in the js console, i tried even to disable javascript... it made no difference. Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

It was angularjs interfering with my form validation...